# Aerospike - How to insert a unique item in a given list using Java?

Tags: java, aerospike

If I run the code below, the value coming from getUserName() gets appended to the list. But if I run it again, same value gets inserted again. My question is, how to make sure the value is appended only once(Unique)?

**My current code**

```
Operation operation = ListOperation.append("names", Value.get(usr.getUserName()));
Record record = client.operate( policy, key, operation );
```

**Example:** Consider the "name" bin to be a list of strings.

```
'LIST["T1", "T2"]'
```

If I add T2 again, the list should remain the same.

Comment: Can you please post the ListOperation class?

Comment: @Jason ListOperation is the built-in class provided by Aerospike
https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListOperation.html

Comment: Your ListPolicy takes flags, and ListWriteFlags have `ADD_UNIQUE` and `NO_FAIL` which you should combine if you want a value to only be added if it's a new unique list element. https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListWriteFlags.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ListOperation.append()`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListOperation.html#append-com.aerospike.client.cdt.ListPolicy-java.lang.String-com.aerospike.client.Value-com.aerospike.client.cdt.CTX...-) can take a [`ListPolicy`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListPolicy.html), which takes flags. For write operations such as this, the [`ListWriteFlags`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListWriteFlags.html) have the fields `ADD_UNIQUE` and `NO_FAIL` which you should combine if you want a value to only be added if it's a new unique list element.

See https://www.slideshare.net/RonenBotzer/asug-tlvmeetup2talk

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i'm assuming that ListOperation is backed by a List since the code isn't available. Assuming it is, Lists maintain order while allowing null values. Sets on the other hand only allow unique, non-null, values so this would be a perfect solution for you.

```java
Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();

values.add("T1");
values.add("T1"); // already contains value
```

**Alternative**
If you need to maintain the order of your Collection but you want unique values, another option would be to check on add if the value already exists OR using Stream#distinct.

```java
List<String> values = ListOperation.values.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the value of that bin keeps updating dynamically... So HashSet wouldn't work for my case.

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by updating dynamically?

Comment: For example, currently there are 2 items stored in the Aerospike database.... New elements keep adding from time to time. So if the element I'm trying to add is already present in the database, it shouldn't create a duplicate

Comment: Not sure if I follow, updates applied during a UDF are atomic. The list cannot receive outside updates while the UDF has the record locked.